# clear json response in angular/ionic3

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I have built a http request to populate json response in a list

```
searchUser(event, key) {
this.storage.get('token').then((authData)=>{
this.authToken = authData.access_token;  
console.log(event.target.value);
if(event.target.value.length > 4) {
var effectedUser = event.target.value;

var headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+this.authToken)
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/mobile_app/user/'+effectedUser;

var response = this.http.get(url, {headers: headers}).map(res =>    res.json())

   .subscribe(data=>{
    this.names = data.result;

  }, Error=>{
  alert(Error)
  });
  }
  })
  }
```

I am able to set the input value using innerHTML and change the focus to next input field like below

```
itemTapped(event, name) {
document.getElementById('effectdusername').innerHTML = name.username;
document.getElementById("userLocation").focus();
document.getElementById("userLocation").scrollIntoView();
return true;
}
```

I wanted to know how can i clear the json response once i have set the input value from the response using innerHTML and the focus is set to next input field.

below is the markup

```
<ion-item>
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Search effected user" (input)="searchUser($event, searchKey)" id="effectdusername"></ion-input>
```

```
<ion-list>  
  <ion-item *ngFor="let name of names" (click)="itemTapped($event, name)">
    <h1>{{name.username}}</h1>
    <p>{{name.email}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list> 

<ion-item>
  <ion-input id="userLocation"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Any kind of suggestion would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Below is the image with the JSON response that i want to clear on focus change
[json response displayed with 2 user names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLn98.jpg)

Comment: By clear do you mean clearing the this.names property?

Comment: yes wanted to clear names JSON response as i do not want the http method to keep running once the element is set.
So the main aim is to kill the searchUser() function

Comment: Angular's http.get observable only runs once per call. So as long as you only call the searchUser method once you should be ok

Comment: In that case i shouldn't bother about destroying the searchUser() function.
Thanks a ton for the clarification.